# calling a modal remotely from the Master Page

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, master-pages, bootstrap-modal

I have a topbar over my main nav. They are both part of the header in the master page. In this topbar, I have a register and a login link. They are both supposed to trigger a modal respectively. (well, the register link actually triggers a series of modals that are part of a registration process).

The modals are not part of the Master Page obviously. They are in a separate page called "register.aspx" and "login.aspx"

My question is: How do I call these modals? I tried the normal Bootstrap Modal invocation but no luck.

I dont figure this out I will make the Default page a static page and run the rest of the site from the Master Page but I'd rather not do that.

This is the code:

master page

```
<div class="top-links">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 email">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="mailto:brazilvagroup@outlook.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> brazilvagroup@outlook.com</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 login">
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#getstarted" href="#getstarted"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Sign up</a></li><%--~/Account/Register--%>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %>!</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%-- Main Nav is down here --%>
```

the register.aspx page

```
<div class="modal" id="getstarted" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create these as separate pages. This is something more easily done by creating them as user controls and importing them into the page, where the modal can than be called by script. Better yet though, don't put the modal markup in the user control as it makes it less portable and re-usable. Reference the user control from a page where the reference can be wrapped in the content area of a dialog.

Basically though, this isn't a good approach. If you want the pages to be separate, don't put the modal HTML code in them. Create them as ordinary .aspx pages without any html markup that would designate it as a bootstrap modal. Then, put your modal markup in the .aspx page or .master and you can put an iframe in the content area of the modal. The design approach already taken is more similar to what you would do with winforms, where a page is a separate form and can be a modal dialog.

Comment: I see what you are saying. User controls is a good idea. I still can't do iframes because of responsiveness, but I still can do jquery .cor to make the call. OK, I think I know where I can go with this.